# How do I move a selection of files into several different directories in one loop?

Tags: powershell

First time toying seriously with Powershell. I'm running into the problem that my little loop doesn't do what I want it to; it creates a list of series names from the files found in a directory and creates the directories needed to hold the files.

```
[TAG]Series first.txt
[TAG]Series something else.txt
File.jpg
etc.
```

This should be sorted into

```
Series first [Sometag]\[TAG]Series first.txt
Series something else [Sometag]\[TAG]Series something else.txt
File.jpg
etc.
```

But I can't get Move-Item to actually move the files into the new directories. It leads to extensionless files or errors stating that the file (directory) already exists.

```bsh
$details = ' [Sometag]'
$series = Get-ChildItem . -Name -File -Filter *.txt |
          % {$_.Replace("[TAG]", "").Split("-")[0].Trim()} |
          Get-Unique 
$series | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -Name $_$details -ItemType Directory
}
```

This is the command that should move the files that it finds using the `$serie` collection into the directories previously created.

```bsh
foreach ($serie in $series) {
    Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *$serie*.txt |
        Move-Item -Destination '.\$serie$details'
}
```

Which results in it complaining that the file already exists. What would be the best way to deal with this, and can I optimize the first two lines?

Comment: `'.\$serie$details'` -> `".\$serie$details"`

Comment: Your `$series` still contains the extension `.txt`, so the 2nd code fragment won't find anything to move.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you! That made all the difference. What a difference ' and " make.

Comment: The difference between "variables are expanded" and 'variables are not expanded'. Just like in many other languages.